# Remove public folder in Laravel 5 using AWS EC2 or Beanstalk

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In local environment I can navigatate to domain.com/app but in AWS it only works if I use domain.com/public/app. I have tried a number approaches to get it to resolve without public folder

I tried 2 different approaches already:

Added .htaccess mod_rewrite but it provides an error below.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

> Laravel NotFoundHttpException in compiled.php line 7610.

I do not want to rename the server.php to index.php as this is not an optimally secure approach.

**In /public/.htaccess I have**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]


</IfModule>
```

Any other way to get http to https **without** using Homestead?

Comment: Which directory are you pointing the domain to?

Comment: Its pointed to public folder. In config app.php I have  'url' => env('APP_URL', 'https://example.com'),

Comment: In that case I would try running `php artisan route:clear && php artisan clear-compiled && php artisan optimize && php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: Tried it and still have to go to example.com/public/app but in localhost i can go directly to example.com/app

Answer (score 0):

In your virtualhost file point documentroot to public folder of laravel

Comment: see this link http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/25/creating-an-apache-virtualhost